# concatenar tres campos en listbox

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

He tratado de que se muestren en un listbox la lista de los usuarios, pero no he logrado que funcione.Si solo quiero mostrar un campo como el nombre, funciona bien, pero necesito que se muestre el nombre y los dos apellidos.

```
<?php


 class mHorarios extends CI_Model
 {

 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
 }

 public function lista_usuarios (){

 $this->db->select('CONCAT( pnombre, '.', apellido_pa , '.', apellido_ma) AS nombre');
 $this->db->order_by('nombre', 'asc');
 $usuarios = $this->db->get('usuarios');



if($usuarios->num_rows() > 0){

      return $usuarios->result();
    }
  }
 }

 ?>
```

Me arroja el siguiente error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$rut_usu
>   Filename: usuarios/vAdministrar_Horarios.php Line Number: 73
>   Backtrace: File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\views\usuarios\vAdministrar_Horarios.php
>   Line: 73 Function: _error_handler File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\cHorarios.php
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$pnombre
>   Filename: usuarios/vAdministrar_Horarios.php Line Number: 73
>   Backtrace:

Comment: Por qué al generar el string del select pones dos comas entre los campos que quieres concatenar?

Comment: Vi un ejemplo en una web en ingles y aparecía de aquella forma, no se si esta bien, quiero concatenar: pnombre, apellido_pa y apellido_ma ejemplo seria algo as:  nombre = Juan Morales Vidal

Comment: Pues creo que eso es lo que te falla, prueba a ponerlo de la siguiente forma: `$this->db->select('CONCAT( pnombre, " ", apellido_pa , " ", apellido_ma) AS nombre');`

Comment: qué error te da?

Comment: Editado, puse el error que me arroja